# MacOS doesn't update custom Services hotkeys (iTerm2 specifically) after editing them in System Preferences

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, finder, iterm2

I'm on OSX Ventura 13.1. I've added a hotkey to open iTerm2 in selected folder, but the new hotkey doesn't appear in Finder menu and doesn't work. How do I synchronise what's actually in Finder and what's in System Preferences?

On the screenshot you can see the System Preferences setting for a hotkey "new iTerm2 Window Here", and how the submenu in Finder>Services doesn't show it (and it doesn't work).

[image: System preferences settings for Finder hotkeys]
[image: The actual hotkeys in the Finder menu - no iTerm hotkey here]

Update: I was able to "fix" this with this workaround:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74152132

But it still doesn't make the Services shortcuts menu work as expected

Answer (score 0):

Try relaunching Finder after defining the shortcut.

Hold Option and right click Finder in the dock. Choose Relaunch. Now select a file or folder in Finder and the shortcut should work.